# ASP.NET Multithreadthing and timing out long-running operations

Tags: asp.net

I have a web service which has to make a call to a database operation if the operation takes more than 10 seconds then I need to exit from the operation and rollback. My understanding is that this can only be done by spawning a thread to carry out the lengthy process and then terminate the thread if it takes longer than certain amount of time. Can you suggest how this can be done or point me to examples where a similar situation is being handled. Is threading within asp.net and desktop application be considered the same, can I use threading concepts of a desktop application and apply it to web service or is there any difference to consider.

Thanks

Comment: Not an ASP.NET Expert, but isn't every request to the asp.net application placed in its own thread? Or are you asking about 1 request utilizing threading? Threading on asp.net is the same as a desktop application.

Comment: @Shawn: threading in ASP.NET is _not_ the same as a desktop application! Every request comes in on a thread pool thread, as opposed to a desktop application, where the Windows Message Queue is a big factor.

Comment: It is within a single request, I need to spawn threads and kill it if it exceeds certain time period. Thanks John for clarifying that it is indeed different

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you right now this could be a serious headache.  Terminating threads without their cooperation can create all sorts of undefined and unexpected behavior.

But if you really want to do this, starting a background thread in ASP.NET is just like a .NET desktop application.  What John means about threading not being the same as a desktop application only applies to how the ASP.NET engine handles requests internally.  You don't really need to worry about that aspect (unless you are blocking on every request).